How should we sort out the "traditional-chinese" and "simplified-chinese" tags?
Let's talk about these tags: traditional-chinese, simplified-chinese.
It seems they're intended to be about traditional/simplified Chinese characters.  I don't believe "simplified Chinese" can refer to anything other than simplified characters.  I'm not sure about "traditional Chinese" (there's a classical-chinese tag).
I've seen people use simplified-chinese because they want a simple answer, which is definitely not what the tag is aiming for.  And we see random questions tagged traditional-chinese or simplified-chinese because the author types using traditional/simplified characters, which is not a useful way to tag questions (it doesn't identify what the question is about).
Since it's usually easier for people to give their opinion if they're given options, here's some possibilities on what to do here:

Do nothing.
Rename the tags to traditional-characters and simplified-characters, and nothing else.
Merge both traditional-chinese and simplified-chinese into the tag traditional-vs-simplified, then rename it traditional-simplified or simplification.
Something I haven't thought of.

What's your thoughts on this?

i’ve difficulty to understand the option 3, particularly renaming “traditional-vs-simplified” to “traditional-simplified”, or “simplication”;  any clarification, please

Perhaps a better way to phrase it is: take the three tags [traditional-chinese], [simplified-chinese] and [traditional-vs-simplified] and replace them with a single tag, which we might call [simplification] or [traditional-simplified], or something else if there's a better option.

in sequence, i would choose for option 2, option 1 & [traditional-simplified]

I went ahead and changed

simplified-chinese to simplified-characters
traditional-chinese to traditional-characters

and added appropriate synonyms.
First, it's an easily reversible change.  And both simplified-chinese and traditional-chinese get confused for other concepts (easy questions/answers, and classical Chinese).  Also it's a bit weird having "Chinese" in tags at this site.
Anything more than this, I wouldn't do without further consultation.
(It looks like many questions with these tags could do with a big of retagging, too.)
